# Basic Java: Error in Return Statement?

Tags: java

I keep getting a return statement error for this section of code. Looks fine to me, maybe someone in here can help?

```
//It returns the index of the number specified by the parameter is
//located. If the number is not found, it returns -1.
private int indexOf(int searchingNum) {
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
        if (numberArray[index] == searchingNum) {
            return index;
        } else 
            return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your indentation suggests that your code does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

for the compiler, this method does not contain a `return` statement that is  **guaranteed** to be executed in any case. you have a `return` in your `for` loop, but the compiler does not know if at least one iteration will be executed, and therefore it is not sure if the `return` statement will be executed

Answer (score 2):

your last `else` is not needed

```
//It returns the index of the number specified by the parameter is
//located. If the number is not found, it returns -1.
private int indexOf(int searchingNum)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
        if (numberArray[index] == searchingNum){
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently of what you have will return -1 always with exception when `numberArray[0]` has `searchingNum`. what you probably meant is this:

```
private int indexOf(int searchingNum)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        if (numberArray[index] == searchingNum) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

also sub the `count` to `numberArray.length` - this will save some time for you in case `count` is not equals to length of `numberArray`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what happens when the for loop is not executed, what will be returned? You have a path that does not return an expected value as specified by the return type of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Its giving missing `return` statment error beacuse all of your `return` statement is in `if-else` statement. There must be atleast on `return` statument outside the scope of all your conditional statements including the loops.

```
private int indexOf(int searchingNum) {
for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
if (numberArray[index] == searchingNum){
  return index;
}
else return -1;
```